# How to do add access to the Win32 API in an OpenFrameworks program?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, openframeworks

I have an OpenFrameworks project in Visual Studio 2008 running on a Windows PC. I need to access the Win32 API. How do I add the Win32 C++ library to my solution? e.g. presumably there is a header file and a DLL I need to include in my solution somehow? Where do I get these and how do I add them into my project? (I'm an OF/VS2008 newb.)

Comment: `#include <windows.h>`. Since you're using Visual Studio, you do not need to obtain that header as it is included.

Comment: @JBentley - thanks, tried that (also tried including WinBase.h). No error on include so headers are there as you say but getting identifier not found compile error when referencing `CreateMutex`. Is there an preface to the API call,  or it's just called like a global function?

Comment: Can you show a minimal code example which demonstrates the problem? I was able to compile and run the following without errors in VS2012: `#include <Windows.h>
int main(){CreateMutex(NULL, true, NULL);}`. Note, including WinBase.h will have no effect as it is included when you include Windows.h

Comment: @JBentley - Pretty much just that. I have `include <Windows.h>` at the top of my file (which compiles with no error) and then, as then `void ofxNCoreVision::_setup(ofEventArgs &e) { CreateMutex(NULL, TRUE, "foo"); etc... }` where `_setup` is called during the startup routine of the OpenFrameworks application. Here's the compiler error: `error C3861: 'CreateMutex': identifier not found`

Comment: Note that <windows.h> defines a preprocessor macro called `CreateMutex` that resolves to `CreateMutexA` or `CreateMutexW` depending up whether `UNICODE` is defined.  The fact that the compiler is complaining about `CreateMutex` without the `A` or `W` suffix suggests that the macro is not defined at the point of your call.  Perhaps Open Frameworks headers are messing with you.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy - ah yes nice clue, thanks.